# Keydown event on ps4 browser doesn't seem to have a key or keycode?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, ps4

I am making this snake-game, and i am trying to make it playable on as many devices as possible. When i loaded my snake website on my ps4 browser, it worked fine, until i tried to move the snake. I didn't have ps4 controller events keys in my javascript, so i tried to find out what the event keys are on a ps4 controller. I tried it with this code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
 window.alert(`key: ${e.key}, keycode: ${e.keycode}`)
// i am using alert() instead of console.log() because the ps4 browsers does not have a console. So the console does not have a console haha
})
```

when i press a button on my controller i get an alert with: *key:  code: undefined*. I have no idea how to figure out if it's possible to let my snake move on ps4, do any of you have a solution? I get the same problem when i connect a keyboard to my ps4 btw

All of my code: https://github.com/LarsVerschoor/LarsVerschoor/tree/main/Snake%20V3.0

Comment: Have you tried `code`? I think `keyCode` has been deprecated. Have you checked out: [_MDN: "Implementing controls using the Gamepad API"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Controls_Gamepad_API)?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl - [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is also modern, but [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) is still a good suggestion. @​Lars - If you were going to use the deprecated key code, it would be `keyCode`, not `keycode`. (But don't, use `key` or `code` instead. :-) )

Comment: When i do that, i get * key:  code: * instead of *key:  code: undefined*

Comment: I will take a look at the gamepad API

Answer (score 0):

You might have to rewrite some of the code but here are the ps4 controller keycodes.

- X = 1
- O = 2
- Sq = 0
- Tri = 3
- R1 = 5
- R2 = 7
- R3 = 11
- L1 = 4

I don't know if this helps but I hope it did

Comment: Please be sure to cite your sources.

Comment: These are not browser keycodes right?

Comment: The source seems to be https://forum.unity.com/threads/ps4-axis-key-codes.396460/, and that's not the keycodes that work in a browser

Comment: It's the keycodes in c#